# Does Unity have Autofac's equivilent of Owned<> to force new instance to be created

Tags: unity-container, ioc-container, autofac

The project I'm on requires we use Unity.  The lifetime managers are correctly set so this is not an issue with setting a lifetime manager.  We have a special case where I need to resolve a service but it needs to freshly resolve every dependency as if it was the original request.  In Autofac I can do this by injecting an Owned.  Does Unity support anything like that or is there a way I can call Resolve and get a fresh set of injections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a Marker interface and registering that interface with a different scope.  Then when I must have a new instance and not a shared instance I use the other interface.

Answer (score 2):

Unity doesn't have equivalent of Autofac's `Owned<>` feature.
As for your problem, I think factories could solve it. You can write your own factory or use Unity Automatic Factories feature. More info on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463%28v=pandp.30%29.aspx).